# Failed to download repository information on Ubuntu Unity 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, ppa, update-manager

When I ran Software Updater I was given an error message saying

> Failed to download repository information, check your internet connection.

This is what it says:

```
W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/icons/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/icons/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found, 
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PPA you've added, [`ppa:upubuntu-com/icons`](https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/ubuntu/icons), doesn't support Ubuntu 16.04. As you can see from [their list of supported releases](http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/icons/ubuntu/dists/), the last supported release is `wily`, or Ubuntu 15.10.

You'll need to either remove that PPA or try to set it to use `wily` instead of `xenial`. Find out which file has that PPA by running `fgrep upubuntu-com /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`, and proceed from there.

If the entry shows up in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, you can edit that file by running `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`, finding the `upubuntu-com` line and either changing `xenial` to `wily` or removing the line.

If the entry shows up in a file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, you can either delete the file or edit it using `sudo nano file-path` and changing `xenial` to `wily`.

After you've done that, run `sudo apt update` again.