# upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 on digitalocean

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

got:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages404 Not Found  ,  
E:Some index files failed to download. They have
been ignored, or  old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Answer: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/324

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to download repository information on Ubuntu Unity 16.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/897587/failed-to-download-repository-information-on-ubuntu-unity-16-04-lts) and [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Answer (score 0):

This solve my issue:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y -r ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/chris-lea-node_js-*.list
```

[source](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/324)